# SpringBoot with mybatis mapper multiple database

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I want implement the following result in mapper.xml, the best practice is ?

```
 <insert id="insertFromODS">
```

INSERT INTO database2.table
FROM  database1.table1 AS tb1 LEFT JOIN database1.table2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id=tb2.id

```
 </insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join over multiple databases

Comment: thanks for your reply; is there a best practice for this ?

Comment: basically you need to separate request to each DB and combine the result manually in your business logic